# surface of revolution and coordinate change. Does order matter?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, surfaces, hyperbolic-functions

*The construction:*

---

Consider $xy=1$ revolved about $y=x$ to bring the surface, $S$ into $\Bbb R^3.$ Then rotate $S$ to get:

$$ x^2+y^2+z^2-4xy-4yz-4zx=-1 $$

Now change the coordinates of $xy=1$ and,

consider $\log(x)\log(y)=1$ revolved about $y=x$ to bring the surface $L$ into $\Bbb R^3.$ Then rotate the surface so that $L$ lies completely in the first octant $(+,+,+).$

Then take $L$ and change the coordinates s.t. every point $p=(x,y,z)$ on the surface becomes $p'=(\log(x),\log(y),\log(z)).$ Define the new surface as $L'.$

> How do you show that $S\ne L'?$

---

The point is, that the order matters here. In one case I revolved $xy=1$ and in the other case I changed the coordinates, revolved the curve and mapped it back with the inverse change of coordinates. I thought that mapping it back would yield the surface of revolution made with $xy=1$ but apparently that's not the case?

Comment: Your question is substantially unclear.  In particular, your statements that begin "Rotate $S$ to get ...", "change coordinates of $xy=1$ ...", "rotate the surface so that $L$ lies completely in the first octant", "change the coordinates s.t. every point ..." do not describe well-defined operations.